# SQL Server insert with stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have been tasked with migrating a website from Rackspace cloud hosting to Godaddy hosting. I also have to move a SQL Server database off the Rackspace cloud and onto the godaddy platform.

I have exported the data successfully and loaded it successfully as well. I manually copied each stored procedure from Rackspace to Godaddy. And I have all the web files loaded correctly on Godaddy as well.

My problem is that when I execute a page that tries to insert a new record into a table through the use of one of the stored procedures, I get an error:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'id', table 'ssmdb1.dbo.coupons'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. The statement has been terminated.

The code of the stored procedure is this:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[insertcc]
     @ccode Varchar(50),
     @ctype Varchar(50),
     @camt Integer,
     @cexpdt DateTime,
     @isused Integer,
     @numdaystosubstart Integer,
     @activationfee Decimal(8,2),
     @templatefee Decimal(8,2),
     @subscriptionamt Decimal(8,2),
     @active Bit,
     @startdate DateTime,
     @expiredate DateTime
AS
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[coupons](ccode, ctype, camt, cexpdt, isused, 
                                numdaystosubstart, activationfee, templatefee,  
                                subscriptionamt, active, 
                                startdate, expiredate)
    VALUES (@ccode, @ctype, @camt, @cexpdt, @isused,
            @numdaystosubstart, @activationfee, @templatefee,
            @subscriptionamt, @active,
            @startdate, @expiredate)
GO
```

So, the table that the record is being inserted into is called coupons. The primary key column is `id`. The stored procedure worked fine on the site on rackspace. I would assume that SQL Server would automatically generate a value for the `ID` column as that column is defined as the primary key. I do not know what I missed on the Godaddy site.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is `ID` defined as an **IDENTITY** column? That's what makes SQL Server handle the auto-numbering - **NOT** the fact that it's a primary key ....

Comment: That was the problem.  When I created the table on godaddy, I used a script that got generated from the Rackspace system.  The IDENTITY parameter was not generated into the script.  I deleted the table (on godaddy), added that parameter, ran the script to create the table, repopulated the table and ran the web page.  I was able to insert a record into the table.  Thanks Marc!

Answer (score 1):

The column ID is not an ID field - which likely was done so to allow inserts.

Now you need to redeclare tham as ID fields, so the "next number" is automatically inserted.

Basically, when you said:

> I have exported the data successfully and loaded it successfully as well.

You were not saying he truth. Your table (at least the one here) has a definition difference between the servers.

I would use a schema sync tool - it is possibly you forgot a lot more "hidden" things that are not obvious.